# How to show associative object array as tbody's td in nuxt

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I want to show property of associative object array, but my code didn't work.
I tried to use v-for loop and wanted to show property information in tbody's td.
I know v-data-table components include :items props,
if I use that :items I could display property.

In future, I will get API and display the some API information.So I need to confirm how to use v-for loop.
I have used nuxt.js and vuetify framework and vue.js.

Please someone help me?

```
    <template>
  <v-data-table :headers="header" dense class="elevation-1">
    <tbody v-for="customer in customers" :key="customer">
      <tr>
        <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {Component,Vue} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class extends Vue{
 header=[
     {text:'name',value:'name'},
     {text:'id',value:'id'},
     {text:'age',value:'age'}
 ]
 customers=[
     {name:'jon',id:1,age:21},
     {name:'dan',id:2,age:23},
     {name:'bob',id:3,age:25},
     {name:'ali',id:4,age:41}

 ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: i hope thats not an typo `... header = [ ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use "v-data-table" with your custom field and access! you can use slot like link bellow:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/data-tables/intermediate/slots.vue

but maybe it's better to